# BCP To Show Full Text Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, bcp

I have a long varchar field that I am exporting to a csv with BCP.  The export goes as it should, however in the actual cell itself the csv file shows `X.XXXXXX+13` instead of `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Am I missing a `Cast()` or BCP switch that could force the csv file to show `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`?  Or since it is BCP this is the output you get?

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max), @filename varchar(max)
Set @filename = 'C:\Test.csv'
Create Table #test (field1 varchar(100))
Insert Into #test (field1) Values
('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
Select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT ''field1'' UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(34)+CAST([field1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34) FROM #Test''" queryout "'
SET @sql = @sql + @filename + '" -c -t, -T -S '+@@SERVERNAME
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field1 VARCHAR(100) );
INSERT  INTO test
        ( field1 )
VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' );

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000) ,
    @filename VARCHAR(4000);
SET @filename = 'C:\temp\Test.csv';
SELECT  @sql = 'bcp "SELECT ''field1'' UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(34)+CAST([field1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34) FROM Test" queryout "';
SET @sql = @sql + @filename + '" -c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
PRINT @sql;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Providing results:

```
field1
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Force text formatting on the column by [adding a preceeding =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates) thus:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field1 VARCHAR(100) );
INSERT  INTO test
        ( field1 )
VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' );

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000) ,
    @filename VARCHAR(4000);
SET @filename = 'C:\temp\Test.csv';
SELECT  @sql = 'bcp "SELECT ''field1'' UNION ALL SELECT ''=''+CHAR(34)+CAST([field1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34) FROM Test" queryout "';
SET @sql = @sql + @filename + '" -c -t, -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
PRINT @sql;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

[image: Excel data]

Comment: that shows the result, but it also adds the = sign to the cell in my csv file.  Is there a way to not have the equal sign exported?

Comment: The = sign is read by Excel and interpreted as the following value being text. You are probably running into an issue with Excel 2007. The article I linked to has information on a workaround for that.